# Magento 2 Install extension but not upgrade Magento via composer

Tags: magento2, composer

So if I understand it right the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` is used for both, upgrading magento 2 and also for installing extensions via composer.

How can I just install the extension without updating the Magento 2 version? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. That command will not update Magento 2 version. That command will only install extension in your Magento 2 setup. To update Magento 2 version, composer commands are used.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the version on the composer file and you must run the `composer install` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` does not install extension from composer. For it, you should use standart composer comands like:

> composer require : - add new data to composer json

or

> composer install or composer update - if you add extension in composer.json with your hands

This is a good turtorial:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

For upgrade magento version you have to run following command :

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
```

But for Update the database schema and data you have to use :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrad
```

so if you run upgrade command it will not upgrade magento version its only install your extension.

For more info check link : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading magento version using composer, just replace 2.2.2 with your version in **composer.json**  file. And run 
`composer update`

```
  "require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.2",
},
```

For installing extension, run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```